# Filter navigation property EF core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

In my repository I try to filter the products with the variants active
but I do not know how because is first time.
I should return all products with or without variants active

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Articolo>> GetArticoliByDivisioneAsync(string divisione)
{
    return await _ctx.Articoli
                     .Where(a => a.Divisione == divisione
                                 && a.Category!= "001")
                     .Include(i => i.Varianti)
                     .Include(i => i.FotoArticoli)               
                     .ToListAsync();
}
```

The field I want to filter on is in `Varianti`.

How can do `.Where(v => v.Active == 1)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Just add your filter to `where` Method

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Articolo>> GetArticoliByDivisioneAsync(string divisione)
{
    return await _ctx.Articoli
        .Where(a => a.Divisione == divisione
                  && a.Category!= "001"
                  && a.Varianti.Any(v=>v.Active == 1))
        .Include(i => i.Varianti)
        .Include(i => i.FotoArticoli)               
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

if you don't need the value of `Varianti` you can remove include part

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Articolo>> GetArticoliByDivisioneAsync(string divisione)
{
    return await _ctx.Articoli
        .Where(a => a.Divisione == divisione
                  && a.Category!= "001"
                  && a.Varianti.Any(v=>v.Active == 1))
        .Include(i => i.FotoArticoli)               
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: I thinks it is important to mention that this will join Varianti table. It can impact performance in some cases.

Comment: i try that but i get 'List<Variante> does not contain definition for Active'... so i posted here the question

Answer (score 1):

To get all products with active variants need to make a projection to new article object and there filter variants

This is the solution

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Articolo>> GetArticoliByDivisioneAsync(string divisione)
{
    return await _ctx.Articoli
                     .Where(a => a.Divisione == divisione
                                 && a.Category!= "001")
                     .Include(i => i.Varianti)
                     .Include(i => i.FotoArticoli)               
                     .Select(x => new Articolo
                    {
                        Codice = x.Codice ,
                        Prezzo = x.Prezzo ,
                        Varianti = x.Varianti.Where(v => v.attivo== 0).ToList(),
                        FotoArticoli = x.FotoArticoli
                    })           
                .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: This is a good workaround for those who can't, or don't want to, directly access EF. Projecting the navigation property does indeed ignore the query filter.

Answer (score 0):

Add to `Where()` clause and use `Any()`:

```
return await _ctx.Articoli
        .Include(i => i.Varianti)
        .Include(i => i.FotoArticoli)
        .Where(a => a.Divisione == divisione
                  && a.Category!= "001"
                  && a => a.Varianti.Any(v => v.Active == 1))

        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Obviously i proved also that

Comment: So i get only the products with at least a variant... but i have also product that has no variant

Comment: So, is the above query returning only entries with `v.Active == 1`? Or is it returning additional entries?

Comment: YES return only the entry with active==1

Comment: And what do you want to happen?

Comment: i proved  && ( a.Varianti.Any(v => v.RdvObsoleta == 0) 
                       || !a.Varianti.Any())) and seems quite works

Comment: Great :) If my answer helped please accept and upvote :)

Comment: Is this what you want: `&& a => (a.Varianti.Any(v => v.Active == 1) || !a.Varianti.Any())`? That should get any `v.Active == 1` and include records that don't exist in `Varianti` @gigiLaTrottola

Comment: i think it works but is not so... All the products and variant are returned: the filter not works!!!

Comment: @gigiLaTrottola can you edit your question to include your exact requirements?

Comment: I improved my requirements and i add the solution